# instance member is not accessible

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I access class functions from inside stack navigator header? Is this possible?
What I'm trying to achieve is to call a function when I press the stack navigator header title.

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: (
                        <View style={header.addressView}>
                            <Text
                                style={header.titleAddress}
                                onPress={() => {
                                  this._show().bind(this);
                                }}>
                            />
                        </View>
                ),
            };
        };

        _show(){
            this.setState({ visibleModal: 1 })
        }

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                visibleModal: null,
            };
        }

        render() {
            ...........

        }
    }

    export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: You have to use setParams and use it. Ref - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#setparams-make-changes-to-route-params

Comment: i dont think this is related to my problem @ashwin-mothilal

Comment: You cannot access this inside StackNavigator so you need to use setParams and use the function as on press in the Text. If you find any other way of accessing this inside StackNavigator please tell us.

Comment: thank you @ashwin-mothilal. Sorry for my ignorance but can you show me a way or a code example how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const showParams = navigation.getParam("show",()=>{});
        //Access the params like this.
        return {
            headerTitle: (
                    <View style={header.addressView}>
                        <Text
                            style={header.titleAddress}
                            onPress={showParams}>
                        />
                    </View>
            ),
        };
    };

    _show(){
        this.setState({ visibleModal: 1 })
    }

    //Too add this.

    componentDidMount(){
      this.props.navigation.setParams({show:()=>this._show()});
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            visibleModal: null,
        };
    }

    render() {
        ...........

    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

This is how you access the variables or states inside a class and make it available for the static navigationOptions function.

[Reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#updating-navigationoptions-with-setparams)