# Can't get throught onPress in static navigationOption function

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to call the _logout() function from onPress of HeaderBackButton.

This is the final code i get ... I tried implement navigation and use only navigation.navigate.... but then i had undefined navigation.

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Späť',
    headerLeft: (
      <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => this._logout()} color="#42BAF8"/>
    )
  }

  render(){
    return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>;
          Welcome Logged Page
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={this._logout} title="Odhlásiť sa"/>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _logout = async() => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
    alert('Bol/a si odlásený/a');
  }
```

I need to call _logout function to get out of the MainScreen to LoginScreen. I really dont know how to do that, cause there is all the time problem with state navigationOptions. I need help with that... thanks for answers

Comment: Try like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444014/instance-member-is-not-accessible/51493297#51493297